# React state not being changed after passed down from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I a setState function being passed down from a parent component, I want to setTheState of the parent setter if the enterKey is pressed. Though, when I set the state nothing happens and I'm still left with an empty array

Here's the code snippet

```js
const { check, setCheck } = props // receive from props
const callApi = async (onEnter) => {
  const res = await callFunction('', data)
  if (res) {
    setResults(res)
    if (onEnter) {
      setCheck(res)
      console.log('check', check) // returns []
    }
  }
```

Returns [] when I log in parent as well

Comment: What is `response`? Did you mean `res`? Where are you returning it too if you're already setting state with `res`? Where is your state? Your code is too incomplete to be able to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of console logging it immediately, wait for it to change, because it's an async operation. You can wrap your log in a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(check);
}, [check]);
```

Comment: I tried this in the parent and it still did not change